# Redefining longtable to add content before and after

Tags: longtable, renewcommand

I'm using Pandoc to generate markdown to LaTeX, and want to add some styling to every longtable. I have been successful in adding content before the table, but not after.

```
\newcommand{\PreTable}{foo}
\newcommand{\PostTable}{bar}

\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\renewcommand{\longtable}[2][]{\PreTable\oldlongtable[#1]{#2}}            % This works
\renewcommand{\longtable}[2][]{\PreTable\oldlongtable[#1]{#2}\PostTable}  % This doesn't - "Misplaced \noalign."
```

In addition to renewcommand, I have tried \def (which also worked with \PreTable), \renewenvironment, and \LetLtxMacro with no success.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: well your \PostTable is not after the longtable, it is after the begin of the longtable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a current latex you could try the hooks provided by it. Documentation about where the hooks are placed can be found in lthooks.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{longtable}

\AddToHook{env/longtable/before}{before}
\AddToHook{env/longtable/after}{after}
\AddToHook{env/longtable/begin}{begin longtable}
\AddToHook{env/longtable/end}{end longtable}
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{ll}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit\\
    Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut & placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]